# Finding N(T) and R(T) with parameters matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I know how to compute the range and kernel with a matrix when it's numbers, but this problem has letter and i'm having difficulty on finding a basis for the nul(T). I can do it for the range as i just need to plug the canonic form and apply the transformation and i'll get 3 basis that will repeat themselves 3 times. But for nul i have no idea:

$T\pmatrix{a11&a12&a13\\a21&a22&a23\\a31&a32&a33}$= $\pmatrix{a11+a12+a13&a21+a22+a23\\a31+a32+a33&0}$

I know that i have to set for example a 11 + a 12 + a13 = 0 and do the same for the 2 others. But how do i find a basis from there? the variables aren't repeating themselves so i'm not able to solve it.

Comment: There are no parameters here, just coordinates (for an appropriate basis of the $3 \times 3$ matrices).

Comment: I meant none parameters obviously.

Comment: Y'know, when a professional mathematician doesn't understand what you say about a fairly elementary mathematics problem, claiming that the interpretation of what you said was "obvious" may not be the best strategy.

Comment: English isn't my main language i thought parameters meant unknown

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is a function from a 9-dimensional space (all 3 x 3 matrices) to a 4D space (all 2 x 2 matrices. It's therefore representable by a 4 x 9 matrix (once you choose a basis for each space). That matrix will be filled with *numbers* and be amenable to the skills you already have.

To find the matrix, you need to pick a basis for each space. Can you do that?

By the way, "I know that i have to set for example a 11 + a 12 + a13 = 0 and do the same for the 2 others." might not be the best place to start from.

Comment: Well the null space is when T(x) = 0, the trivial solution. So i assume to find the 0 solution, you need to set everything equal to 0 and then solve?

You'd have 3 equations:
a11 + a12 + a13 = 0
a21 + a22 + a23 = 0
a31 + a32 + a33 = 0
Then set everything in term of the others? this is the only way i see of doing it and i'm stuck

Comment: I repeat: "To find the matrix, you need to pick a basis for each space. Can you do that?"

Comment: Well for the matrix 3*3 there's 9 dimension (e1, e2... until e9) and for the matrix 2*2 the dimension of the basis is 4 (e1, e2, e3, e4)

Comment: What do you mean by "e2" as a basis element for the space of $3 \times 3$ matrices? I want to be certain we're talking about the same thing.

Comment: e1 as the representation of the canonic basis, for example here i have a matrix 3*3, e1 will have a 1 on the term a11 and the rest of the matrix is 0